# Array Values as Object Properties with PDO

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, pdo, properties

I want to store array values as object properties.  I am following an example for mysqli but I want to use PDO instead.

I have a user class:

```
class User {

public $id;
public $username;
public $password;
public $first_name;
public $last_name;

public static function find_all_users(){
    global $database;
    $result_set = $database->query($sql);
    return $result_set;
  } //end method
} //end User class
```

I have connected to my database using the following database class.
Note:  The constants DB_SERVER etc. are defined elsewhere and included in a file

```
class Database{

public $connection;

function __construct(){
    $this->open_db_connection();
}//end of constructor

public function open_db_connection(){
   try{
      $this->connection = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_SERVER .';dbname='. DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
      $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   }catch(PDOException $e){
      echo 'Server Error: ' . $e->getCode(;
   }//end catch block
}//end of method    

public function query($sql){
    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
} //end query method

$database = new Database();
```

I want to create an object from the User class and use that class' properties to access my data.

```
$user = new User();
$user->id = $result_set['id'];
$user->username = $result_set['username'];
$user->password = $result_set['password'];
$user->first_name = $result_set['first_name'];
$user->last_name = $result_set['last_name'];
echo $user->id;
```

In mysqli this is *would* be done by putting the following:

```
public static function find_all_users(){
   global $database;
   $result_set = $database->query($sql);
   mysqli_fetch_array($result_set);
   return $result_set;
   } //end method
```

The error I get is 
"Undefined index: id"
"Undefined index: username"
"Undefined index: password"
"Undefined index: first_name"
"Undefined index: last_name"

I think my error is from the fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC). I should be getting a value from my echo statement.  echo $user->id;

What is a better fetch method that works similarly to mysqli_fetch_array for PDO?

Below is when I print_r $result_set:

[image: print_r of $result_set]

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What's the problem?

Comment: ... and even after the last edit, you didn't clarify the situation. Please, tell what's the exact problem, why and what you want to get.

Comment: You are making a PDO connection but then have a call to `mysqli_fetch_array()` which isn't going to work. `find_all_users` should just return the value from `$database->query($sql)`. Although `$sql` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere either...

Comment: If you want an object why not use `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`

Answer (score -1):

`fetchAll()` returns a 2-dimensional array. You need to loop over the elements:

```
$all_users = array();
foreach ($result_set as $result) {
    $user = new User();
    $user->id = $result['id'];
    $user->username = $result['username'];
    $user->password = $result['password'];
    $user->first_name = $result['first_name'];
    $user->last_name = $result['last_name'];
    $all_users[] = $user;
    echo $user->id;
}
```

Comment: So where is `$result_set` coming from?

Comment: @Dharman I assumed it was `$result_set = $db->query("SELECT ...");`